# Alter user with superuser not working

Tags: postgresql

In my postgresql 
psql console:

```
postgres-# alter user serf with superuser
postgres-# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 lord      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB              | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 serf      |                                                | {}

postgres-#
```

There is also no feedback like "ALTER ROLE" which should appear. The final result shows the user 'serf' is still not super user.

Comment: I have forgot the ';'

Answer (score 1):

SQL statements need to be terminated with a `;`

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-4)

> input lines are sent to the server when a command-terminating semicolon is reached. **An end of line does not terminate a command.** Thus commands can be spread over several lines for clarity

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

---

Also pay attention to [the change of the prompt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-EXAMPLES)

By default the prompt is `=>` and changes to `->` to indicate a statement that without a `;`

For the superuser the prompt is `=#` and changes to `-#` for unfinished statements. Seeing that you enter the `alter role` statement at a `-#` prompt means that you have already entered something before that without terminating that statement with `;`

My [.psqlrc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN100589) contains:

```
\set PROMPT2 '...> '
```

To make the continuation prompt more obvious, so entering multi-line commands looks like this:

```
psql (9.6.1)

postgres=> select * 
...> from 
...> foobar;
```